# Bootstrap centering issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On this page: (link removed)

I'm starting to build a tumblr theme, and I have decided to build it using bootstrap. If you click the little I info button in the left corner, a div comes down with a user picture and description. The user picture and description appear as I want them to, but they are off center. I'd like them to be centered. I've tried < center >, using a fluid width container, etc with no avail. I also checked and bootstrap.css and the bootstrap.min.js are properly linked to the page.

Any help with this would be GREAT!

My code:

```
      <div class="container-fluid" id="foo" style="z-index:5; display:none; height:auto;">  
       <center>
       <div class="container-fluid" style="height:auto;">
       <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2" style=" margin-top:1%;"><img class="avatar-style-circle" src="{PortraitURL-128}" /><br/><h3>{AuthorName}</h3></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:blue; margin-top:3%;"><p style="text-align:justify;">{Description}<br/></p></div></div></div>

   <div class="container-fluid" style="height:auto; margin-bottom:2%;">
    <center>
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    <br/>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">   <a href="{BlogURL}ask" button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Ask</a>

    <a href="{BlogURL}archive" button class="btn btn-default" button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Archive</a>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="z-index:5; margin-left:13%;">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --></center>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
    {block:ifShowInfoButton}

   <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"><i class="fa  fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="position:absolute; margin-left:0.4%; margin-top:0.4%; color:{color:Info Button Color};"></i></a>


     {/block:ifShowInfoButton}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the col on the picture from md-2 to md-4.

Or change the col on the text from md-8 to md-10 (better)!

It works on a 12 grid system and currently it is only using 10 columns out of 12, which is why it appears to align to the left :)

You can also use [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

Answer (score 0):

papakia's answer is correct however you could also add an empty column in front of your image column that is col-md-2 this will sometimes help not throw off the scale of other items if they are already tuned to your liking.

Comment: You shouldn't add markup that is purely for styling purposes (as with the case of the empty column).